# Automatic create new page in IText7

Tags: c#, itext7

i am trying to build a PDF using itext7. I have to load content using a loop. If the content exceeds the page size, is there any way to automatic create a new page?

i was thinking something like

```
foreach(var item in myModel)
{
   // create new paragraph, and add to page
   if(pageIsfull)
   {
      doc.NewPage();
      // then add content to my new page
   }
}
```

The page i create is by doing

```
PdfPage page9 = pdf.AddNewPage(ps);
```

Then i run my foreach and it only uses page9 and does not add a new one. Is it because i create the page wrong?

Comment: if my memory serves me right, itext will create page for you automatically. but you can always force a page break using `document.Add(new iTXLElement.AreaBreak(AreaBreakType.NEXT_PAGE));`.

Comment: I does not in my case. Maybe i am not doing it right. Gonna edit my question

Comment: You show `create new paragraph, and add to page` instead of (excerpts of) the actual code. Thus, we cannot tell whether our not you're doing it right.